# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Getting sporadic BSOD while using Studio

Tags: eclipse, windows-xp, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am using Windows XP Service pack 3. The OS gets restarted (it crashes) when using Worklight.

I don't know what's problem: the system or Eclipse...
Can any one know please help me to solve this issue?

[image]

Comment: What is your Worklight version? How did you install Worklight? Is this the Developer Edition? Are you customer? Did you try installing on another machine? Does it happen there as well? Doe some debugging yourself first...

Comment: @IdanAdar IBM Work-light Version 6.1.First am install the eclipse then am install IBM work-light from eclipse market.am not a customer.yes am install another machine same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this webpage from IBM: 
[Operating systems for IBM Worklight 6.1.0](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=66C745D01E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36)

Windows XP is not a supported version of Windows in Worklight. It may work, it may not work. Either way it is not supported in Worklight 6.0 and above.

The last version of Worklight that [supported XP is Worklight 5.0.6](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/prodguid/v1r0/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=C2E8EF801E8711E28ACF6F870925FE36).

---

You can download previous releases here:

- 5.0.6.1: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.5.0.6.1.zip
- 6.0.0.1: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/iws_update_site_wde.6.0.0.1.zip

**NOTE:** The downloads above are not the most recent versions of these releases; they are not maintained, and only customers can receive support and ifixes for them. If possible you should upgrade your system and use the latest Developer Edition - 6.1.0.

Comment: Thanks.How can i install Work-light 5.0.6